# How to 'build' a node js application?

Tags: node.js, build

I have a `node.js` application that run as a application server.
It is deployed on an `Ubuntu 20.04` machine running on `AWS`, uses `nginx` as a reverse proxy and `PM2` as a service starter.

Everything seems perfectly configured.

What looks strange to me, is that I have a `React` application, in a similar environment, but, before to move it on the server, I `run build` it, so creating a sort of packed and not easily human readable application.

My question is: **Is there the need to do the same with a `node.js` application?**

And, in case of positive answer, **How to 'build' a `node.js` application?**

Comment: The "build" of web application serves mainly the purpose of minifying and packaging JS (and sometimes CSS) code so it can me more efficiently downloaded. There is no need to do the same for server-side code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to build a normal nodejs application.

What you mean is the use of a bundler e.g. webpack and a javascript compiler e.g. babel. To create a react application, you usually use a tool like create-react-app that sets up all this stuff for you. For react you need the compilation beacause you use the jsx syntax that browsers do not understand. In addition to that a bundler has some more advantages.

Check out this video if you want to know more about it:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5IG4UmULyoA

Comment: The video is interesting, because I have a problem bundling a React application.
Please, give a look at this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70449591/react-application-gives-an-error-when-running-after-after-bundle

Answer (score 2):

No you don't have to build anything for node.js you just have to run the server. for client side apps you need to build and serve the Dist through web servers like apache or nginx.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of node applications these days will be written in TypeScript.
Node itself does not run typescript, it runs JavaScript.
Therefore you will need a build step if you're using TypeScript.

Building the project depends on the tools utilized.
The build script can be as simple as calling `tsc index.ts`.

Afterwards you will have to start the application calling `node index.js` with `index.js` being your build output.